# chackra ui container doesn't work properly

Tags: reactjs, next.js, chakra-ui

I am learning chakra ui and when I use Container component, there is no margin in the screen.
I checked the dev tools and I noticed this:

[image]

this is my code:

```
import { Container, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react"
<VStack>
  <Container maxW="container.xl">Extra-Large Container</Container>
  <Container maxW="container.lg">Large Container</Container>
  <Container maxW="container.md">Medium Container</Container>
  <Container maxW="container.sm">Small Container</Container>
</VStack>
```

Comment: I think you'll have to wrap your App tree with a `ChakraProvider` for it to work as expected.

Comment: Thank you so much man, it'working 